# What is this c. 1948 private plane with a sliding canopy?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

[image]

([YouTube](https://youtu.be/OYb7ZNxcrwM?t=9m38s))

What is this private plane with a sliding canopy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like a variant of the [Ryan Navion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Navion), probably the North American L-17A aka [the poor man's mustang](http://www.warbirdalley.com/l17.htm).

[image: Ryan Navion]

North American L-17 Navion, Camarillo Airport Museum, Camarillo, California, USA; By [Howcheng](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Howcheng) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5123506)